# How to open chrome extension page programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am a new one for the extension. I want to open a chrome extension page programmatically. Eg:

```
chrome-extension://njlkegdphefeellhaongiopcfgcinikh/options.html
```

When I click the web page button or link I want to open the particular extension tab.

I tried many ways. Directly call using javascript and so many ways. But I couldn't find the proper solution. Anybody have any idea.

(My target is using JavaScript to open the extension tab)

Comment: What errors or bad results are you getting? You need to be more specific in what you have tried.

Comment: @abraham No errors. But no output :(. I tried href, and window.open and etc.

Comment: Hi I don't need to create a new one but where as i want to reopen the same on the browser extension icon

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is one of the solutions:

1. Make sure your content script runs on the page on which you are clicking on the button.
2. When you click on button on web page, add event listener from content script and in the event listerner pass a messgae to background.

   ```
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage({message: 'buttonClicked'}, 
     function() { 
       /* callback */ 
     });
   ```
3. In your background script, listen to the message from content script.

   ```
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
     if (request.message == 'buttonClicked') {
     // Create a new tab with options page
    }
   });
   ```
4. To create a new tab with options.html page, you can do this

   ```
   chrome.tabs.create({
     active: true,
     url:  'options.html'
   }, null);
   ```

Comment: Hi I don't need to create a new one but where as i want to reopen the same on the browser extension icon

Answer (score 2):

The web extension API includes a [`runtime.openOptionsPage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/openOptionsPage) method for just this purpose. To use it:

1. You must have an [options page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Options_pages) defined.
2. Call `browser.runtime.openOptionsPage()` (or `chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage()`, depending on the browser you're working with) from your background script.

Though this message is ostensibly part of `runtime`, it seems to only work correctly when called from a background script.

[MDN docs are here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/openOptionsPage)

Comment: If someone wonders how to open options on icon click here is related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70216500/chrome-action-is-undefined-migrating-to-v3-manifest