# how to trigger a browser add-on when loading a html page

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, browser, add-on

I'm trying to create a HTML website that will trigger a specific firefox add-on when I load the page, is that possible?

I searched around but found nothing about it.
How can I make my page interact with the browser's add-ons and trigger some of it's events?

Thanks for reading. any insight will be helpful.

Comment: I think it works the other way around: put something (like a comment) in your HTML page and instruct the extension to determine that particular comment signature. Here is a Chrome extension that is triggered automatically when it determines the response to be a JSON: https://github.com/nikrolls/json-formatter.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Alex that's great, but the problem is that the extension I'm trying to trigger isn't mine so I can't tweak it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better Google search pointed me towards [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761819/how-to-open-chrome-extension-page-programmatically#answer-22763218) on stackoverflow which is for Chrome.

...and then after I knew what I was looking for, I found the mozzila documentation regarding sending a message to an extension [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage)

Syntax as seen on mozzila documentation:

```
var sending = browser.runtime.sendMessage(
  extensionId,             // optional string
  message,                 // any
  options                  // optional object
)
```

The message is what you will want to figure out based on your use case

EDIT: The SO answer provided in my answer should help you quite a lot, as the Firefox API is same as Chrome's Chromium API

Comment: Thanks A LOT, that's really what I was looking for!!

Comment: Glad it helped :)